Integrating the multivariate normal distribution over an ellipse
I have learned that if we have two real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ that follow the centered multivariate normal distribution, this means that there exists a $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix $A$ with positive eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ such that for all solid regions $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, the probability that some $\mathbf{X} = (X, Y) \in \Omega$ is given by the double integral
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X} \in \Omega) = \dfrac{\sqrt{\det(A)}}{2\pi} \int \int_{\Omega} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^TAx} \, dA
\end{equation}
I want to evaluate $\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X}^T A \mathbf{X} \leq 1)$ (that is, the probability $\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X} \in \Omega)$ where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is the solid ellipse arising from the equation $x^T Ax \leq 1$).
My overall idea was to use the Principal Axis Theorem. This states that if we have a quadratic polynomial in the form $q(\hat{x}) = \hat{x}^T A\hat{x} + b \cdot \hat{x} + c$, then we have
\begin{equation}
q(\hat{x}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i u_i^2 + \sum_{i = 1}^n (v_i \cdot b)u_i + c
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of the matrix $A$, $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is an orthonormal eigenbasis of the matrix $A$ in the order corresponding to the order of the eigenvalues (this is guaranteed to exist by the Spectral Theorem, because $A$ is symmetric), and $u_i = v_i \cdot \hat{x}$ are our principal axes.
In particular, if we just have $q(\hat{x}) = \hat{x}^T A\hat{x}$, then we also have $q(\hat{x}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i u_i^2$. So, our region of integration $\Omega$ is actually just $\lambda_1 u_1^2 + \lambda_2 u_2^2 \leq 1$.
Now, to integrate over this elliptical region, my idea was to transform it to a circular region then transform the coordinates from Cartesian to polar. My work is as follows:

Let $(u, v) = (\sqrt{\lambda_1}x, \sqrt{\lambda_2}y)$. Then the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}}$.
The integral then becomes

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X} \in \Omega) &= \dfrac{\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}}{2\pi} \int \int_{u^2 + v^2 \leq 1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u^2 + v^2)} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}} \, du \, dv \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int \int_{u^2 + v^2 \leq 1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u^2 + v^2)} \, du \, dv \\
\end{align*}
Now, a polar substitution (we let $(r, \theta)$ correspond to $(r \cos{\theta}, r \sin{\theta}) = (u, v)$) turns the above integral into
\begin{align*}
&\, \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} \, r \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} \, r \, dr\\
&= \left[ -e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}  \right]_0^1 \\
&= 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= 1 - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e}}
\end{align*}
I have shown all my work above. Now, I am confused because the answer I am receiving is a constant; it does not depend on the original matrix $A$ nor its two eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. The reason I am doubtful about this is because $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ determine the region of integration (they determine the ellipse we are integrating over), so shouldn't the result of the integral depend on them?

You answered the question yourself: The rescaled Jacobian cancels out the rescaled boundaries,  a happy coincidence. Try this with basically any other region and it won't be this nice.
